# How to get decimal value from divide in fish shell

Tags: fish

`math 5/2` returns 2.

I want 2.5 -- how do I get decimal values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can "force" `math` to return fractions by default -- use the `-l` option to `bc`:

```
$ math 5/2
2

$ function bc
      command bc -l $argv
  end

$ math 5/2
2.50000000000000000000
```

Comment: That's a calculator that the `math` funcation uses: do `type math` at a fish prompt.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to one of your config.fish files

`set -x BC_ENV_ARGS ~/.bc.cfg`

Then create a .bc.cfg file to tell it out many decimal places to display

`echo "scale = 5" >> .bc.cfg`

This will:

math 5/2

2.50000

Answer (score 1):

you have to force floating point division instead of integer division

`math 5/2.0`

Comment: It works in fish version 3.0.2, resulting in `2.5`.

Comment: > Fish 1.x and 2.x releases relied on the bc command for handling math expressions. Starting with fish 3.0.0, fish uses the tinyexpr library and evaluates the expression without the involvement of any external commands

.... 
Good.